# 'system.network' is only allowed for packaged apps, but this is a extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to get the local IP address of the device but when I add the permission `system.network` I am getting the warning

```
'system.network' is only allowed for packaged apps, but this is a extension.
```

What does it mean by **packaged app** and if it will work after publishing, how can I test the extension locally?

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Fetcher",
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "description": "Internet download manager",
    "icons": {
        "128": "icon_128.png",
        "48": "icon_48.png",
        "16": "icon_16.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "detectors/audio_detector.js",
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["app.js"]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "<all_urls>",
        "system.network"
    ]
}
```

Comment: It means the deprecated [chrome apps](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps) which won't run in Chrome soon. You can't use this API in extensions.

Comment: thanks, I just figure that out.